# Unable to fetch complete records from bulk query batch result

Tags: rest-api, json, python, simple-salesforce

I am using [simple-salesforce](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/simple-salesforce/latest/simple-salesforce.pdf) python library using REST to call bulk services which is working fine till calling but for large dataset library continuously poll the batch status and spit all result (in my case it is **1mn**) but I am getting only 7lac records in python codebase, I double checked the load jobs which displayed the total record in processed state.

In other [case](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/asynch_api_code_curl_walkthrough.htm) when I tried the same with csv it stream out whole data with xml content type. But with rest I am getting incomplete data.

What should I suppose to do for whole data, I checked with library and found it should stream data or chunk data through loop instead giving directly.

Answer (score 2):

simple_salesforce has a [bug](https://github.com/simple-salesforce/simple-salesforce/issues/280) in its Bulk API implementation. It only retrieves the first batch of results from a Bulk Query job. This is why you do not retrieve complete results.

Consider using [salesforce-bulk](https://pypi.org/project/salesforce-bulk/) instead, which uses simple_salesforce for authentication but has its own, correct, implementation of the Bulk API and supports multiple result batches.

Comment: Trying same but getting result through `bulk.get_all_results_for_query_batch` taking indefinite time for 1mn record, which is not so huge.

Comment: I don't know why that might be, @Shashank - it works fine for me. Feel free to open another question if you can't work it out, with some more debugging details.

Comment: I got stuck in snippet are as: `for result in bulk.get_all_results_for_query_batch(batch):
    result = json.load(IteratorBytesIO(result))
    for row in result:
        print(row)`

It goes in indefinite loop. I am following this codebase: https://github.com/heroku/salesforce-bulk#bulk-query

Comment: @Shashank I know that that library works because I [use it in my own project](https://gitlab.com/davidmreed/amaxa/blob/master/amaxa/amaxa.py#L758). I can't tell you from what you're showing here why it's not working for you. I would suggest you open a new question since this is a separate issue.